# The key value expired during drm development

Tags: cobalt

The key value expired during drm development, so I called back using SbDrmSessionUpdateRequestFunc,

`'LOG (ERROR) << "Unknown session update request ticket:" << ticket << "."  A log will appear.`

1. Why is this log coming out?
2. Is the session_id value the same until the video starts and ends?

Answer (score 0):

ticket should be kSbDrmTicketInvalid if the update request was generated by the DRM system.